# golang: go run is always running old code even after changes

Tags: go

I have a weird issue with golang. I run the command (like everytime):

```
go run main.go
```

Then I made some change into my code and then I run again:

```
go run main.go
```

But the executed code is the old version of the code. So I tried some stuff:

- Reboot the computer
- Delete all the temporary binaries into temp folder
- Reinstall go
- Delete and put back my code
- Remove some file

But it is still running my old version of the code. I didn't find solution about this issue, and the few post about it doesn't give a solution ([here](https://www.reddit.com/r/golang/comments/5g7ci4/go_program_running_old_code/) and [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/womzrEYpfjc)).

About my configuration it is the following:

- Raspberry pi running Raspbian (updated)
- Go version 1.8.1

I hope you can help me !
Thank in advance!

Best regards,

Comment: Is `main.go` the file that was modified, and are you sure you're `go run`ing the correct `main.go` file?

Comment: Did you happen to switch the location of the project while working on it? Your editor may be saving the changes in the old file location.

Comment: @Adian main.go is not the modified file (there is a lot of .go files into my project). And yes it is the correct main.go file

Comment: @Gavin No I didn't switch my location of the project. I tried to directly change a file of the project but it didn't worked

Comment: @Majonsi: Add the output from these commands to your question: `go version`, `go env`, and `SRC=main.go && ls -l $SRC && cat $SRC && go run -x $SRC`

Comment: Try deleting `$GOPATH/pkg`

Comment: That's only specific to this one project; in other projects you don't have that problem?

Comment: @tkausl I tried but it didn't work. Same when I delete the entire $GOPATH folder and then extract it again from the go archive

Comment: My best recommendation would be not to use `go run` at all, honestly. Go is not a scripting language - just build the application and run it.

Comment: @Adrian `go run` will compile the code (into a temporary folder) and then run it. So it change nothing. So I advise you to read (again?) the go documentation just [here](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Compile_and_run_Go_program)

Comment: But it doesn't work the same, because go run targets a file, while build/install targets a package, which is the level of granularity expected in Go. Go run is fine for a one off run of a single file script, but my recommendation stands: don't use go run. It implies a usage pattern that doesn't fit with Go. Just build and run your project normally.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay! 
The problem come from the imports. In the code some imports was calling old version of the code.

Answer (score 1):

I think your `GOPATH` is pointing to a wrong folder. Please, run `go env` to make  sure that it is pointing to the right directory. If not set it to location where go files are. Please, take into account that `go run` usually does not need a file specification and if you do you have to list defacto all files of your app that main.go depends upon.

Have a look ``[here](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Compile_and_run_Go_program)

Comment: "_take into account that go run usually does not need a file specification_…"   What??

Comment: @Windys My GOPATH is pointing to the right folder. And I don't have to specify all the file of my project because my main function is only on my main.go file.